# External link redirection

Tags: seo, redirects

I am rather new at SEO and recently I was asked to make some of our external links as 307 redirect. The reason behind this is to have clean links and to retain the pagerank juice.

I've set up the codes to do so, however I am wondering if 307 is the proper relocation code, especially considering that it says it's meant to be temporary everywhere...

Comment: Define "clean links". What makes you think a "307 redirect" will "retain the pagerank juice"? Generally, a redirect will be treated like an ordinary link, unless the script that is triggering the redirect is blocked from crawling. (Be wary, trying to "retain pagerank" by massaging external links is an outdated concept and generally best avoided.)

Comment: By clean links I mean clean URLs (for example, www.site.com/go/link/ instead of long URLs with multiple tags). As far as the pangerank juice goes, we want to avoid giving away our pagerank to those links for the moment...

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be much call for 307 redirects. Moz has a [pretty good explanation](https://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection):

> The exception to this is when content is really moved only temporarily (such as during maintenance) AND the server has already been identified by the search engines as 1.1 compatible. Since it's essentially impossible to determine whether or not the search engines have identified a page as compatible, it is generally best to use a 302 redirect for content that has been temporarily moved.

Comment: But in this case, since those links are external links, should we consider them "temporarily moved" ?